# hide an entry from Toc in latex

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

I would like to know how I can hide a section from the table of contents but without loosing the section number in the body of the document. For example, in this *tex* file I loose the number for `hide`, and all the sequences are damaged:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{uno}
\section{dos}
\section*{hide}
\section{tres}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it will be nice also ommit the page number in the right..i just need

SectionName.................SectionNumber

SectionName2................SectionNumber2

...etc.

Answer (score 76):

I think you are looking for

```
\section*{hide}
\addtocounter{section}{1}
```

or make it into a command:

```
\newcommand{\toclesssection}[1]{\section*{#1}\addtocounter{section}{1}}
```

EDIT:

Okay, I think I understand what is wanted now (and it makes more sense then the answer I gave).  Here is a command that you can use to suppress adding a section, subsection, etc. to the TOC.  The idea is to temporarily disable `\addcontentsline`.

```
\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}
...
\tocless\section{hide}
\tocless\subsection{subhide}
```

Comment: OP said "without losing the section number in the body"

Comment: the problem remains and appear other incongruency. in Toc the section tres has the number 3, in the body has the number 4.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what was wanted.

Comment: mmm I don't understand the logic in the set of command, can you give me a hint in English?...im trying to use the tocless command but doesn't work.

Comment: Dang it!  I forgot to add the \nocontentsline command.  I don't know what my problem is.  Anyway, the idea is to set \addcontentsline to a no-op when evaluating the \section command.

Comment: A small improvement: to reference the hidden sections elsewhere in the document you need to add the `\label` inside of the group. For example, `\newcommand{\toclesslab}[3]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2\label{#3}}\egroup}` will fix it. Usage: `\toclesslab\section{Motivation}{s:motivation}` will keep the section from appearing the TOC, but you can still reference it with `\ref{s:motivation}` or similar.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3805470/431528 for an answer which doesn't cause formatting issues.

Comment: thanks! works like a charm for subsubsections as well :-)

Comment: my opinion is the EDIT should be first in this answer - in short, define `\tocless` then use it in front of whatever

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to say thanks for Ivans great hint!
(I was just googling for something similar for my customized (Sub)Appendix{} commands:

```
\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}

\newcommand{\Appendix}[1]{
  \refstepcounter{section}
  \section*{Appendix \thesection:\hspace*{1.5ex} #1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix \thesection}
}
\newcommand{\SubAppendix}[1]{\tocless\subsection{#1}}
```

Maybe this is useful for someone else, too...)

Answer (score 3):

have just come here from [a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791950/remove-specific-subsection-from-toc-in-latex) The answer above didn't quite work as it gave some formatting issues, but a [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791950/remove-specific-subsection-from-toc-in-latex/3805470#3805470) seemed to do the trick