# Remove specific subsection from TOC in LaTeX

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hide an entry from Toc in latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785260/hide-an-entry-from-toc-in-latex)

```
Appendix
 A Section 1
     A.1 Subsection 1
     A.2 Subsection 2
 B Section 2
```

Is there a way to get rid of Subsection n, but still have the subsection numbered in the document (i.e. not using \subsection*)?

I thought about limiting the TOC depth, but that does not seem to be possible for just the Appendix?

Comment: you might find [this so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785260/hide-an-entry-from-toc-in-latex) helpful

Comment: quite close, but this also affects the layout of subsections (the below spacing is totally wrong).

Comment: why do you want to do this? (is there some underlying problem that may be easier to solve in latex?)

Comment: It's just university guidelines...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's one (sort of hackish but not too bad) way to work this:

All wrapped up, you just add a new command `hiddensubsection`, given by

```
\newcommand{\hiddensubsection}[1]{
    \stepcounter{subsection}
    \subsection*{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}\hspace{1em}{#1}}
}
```

Then you create your notoc subsection using this instead of `\subsection`:

```
\hiddensubsection{sectionname}
```

The way it works is by manually incrementing the subsection counter and then creating an unnumbered subsection with the subsection counter as part of the title. You may need to tweak the spacing between number and title, but i couldn't see any difference.

Obviously you could do the same thing for sections and subsubsections if needed

Comment: What do you do if the * operator doesn't work. For me, its using "*" as the actual title and treating the actual heading like regular text in a new paragraph.

Comment: I personally found using `1ex` instead of `1em` for the `\hspace` to be correct.

Comment: This works. However, it changes the subsection counter. Is it possible to use this solution and still use `\ref` properly?

Comment: @tiago Yes, just use ```\refstepcounter``` instead of ```\stepcounter``` in the code above and ```\ref```` will be updated!