# Hide sections from ToC in Latex

Tags: latex

I would like to hide sections of Appendix from the table of contents, without losing the section number in the body of the document and section should be possible to reference.

I found a solution: [hide an entry from Toc in latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785260/hide-an-entry-from-toc-in-latex)

```
\newcommand{\toclesslab}[3]. 
{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2\label{#3}}\egroup}
```

Usage: \toclesslab\section{Motivation}{s:motivation}

but it is showing two errors first after the command:

```
Argument of \label has an extra }.
Missing $ inserted.
```

second after the row

```
LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
Undefined control sequence.
Missing number, treated as zero.
```

and it's not possible to use \label

is there a way to hide a section without losing number and still be referencable?

I have tried this too [Remove specific subsection from TOC in LaTeX [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791950/remove-specific-subsection-from-toc-in-latex)

Minimal reproducible example: https://latexbase.com/d/498aec5c-d490-47d5-a469-9c6df79a2962

Thank you

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: here it is: https://latexbase.com/d/498aec5c-d490-47d5-a469-9c6df79a2962

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible by using toc depth, but it is important to reset the depth back to the previous value or it can break other lists.

```
\appendix
\section*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}

%Here's the place to hide section from ToC 
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}

\section{Appendix section}
\label{appendixSection}
Text

%At the end of the appendix it has to be set to the previous value
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
```